# .NET Query with list as sql parameter

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, fortify

```
public SqlDataReader GetDataReader(List<SqlParameter> parameterValues){

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
    cn.ConnectionString = SQLConnectionObj.ConnectionString;
    cn.Open();
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
    cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameterValues.ToArray());
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = SelectStatement;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    return sReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
}
```

When I try to add this for IN condition variable in select query,it fails.
Need to use this only for Fortify fix.Tried with dictionary Sql parameter.It works but increases the issue count up.

Please help me with this.And also if there is anything new which you want to add feel free to add those too.

But the following code works:-

```
   public SqlDataReader GetDataReader(Dictionary<string, string> qParams)
    {
    SqlCommand SQLCommandObj = new SqlCommand(SelectStatement, 
    SQLConnectionObj);
     string query=SelectStatement;

    if (qParams.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (string key in qParams.Keys)
        {
            string value = qParams[key];
            SqlParameter par = new SqlParameter();
            par.ParameterName = key;
            par.Value = value;
            SQLCommandObj.Parameters.Add(par);
          }
    }

    foreach(SqlParameter par in SQLCommandObj.Parameters)
    {
        string key = par.ParameterName;
        string value = par.Value as string;
        query=query.Replace(key, value);
    }
    if (qParams.Count > 0)
    {
        SQLCommandObj.CommandText = "";
        SQLCommandObj.CommandText = query;
    }

    SQLCommandObj.CommandTimeout = CustomCommandTimeout;
    return SQLCommandObj.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
}
```

Comment: What's in `SelectStatement`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled select query is like select *from clothes where material IN (@material) ...and there are also multiple IN conditions in sql statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass string parameter with \`IN\` operator in stored procedure SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872056/how-to-pass-string-parameter-with-in-operator-in-stored-procedure-sql-server-2)

Comment: There are some problems with your code - starting with the fact that you don't close or dispose any of the `IDisposable` instances (`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, and `SqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable`). Since you are working with .Net and Sql Server, look into Table valued parameters - in most cases, that's the best practice way to pass an Array like structure to SQL Server.

Comment: @ZoharPeled SqlConnection,command and datareader all are there.Just need  to use that block fo Fortify..

Comment: But they are not being disposed...

Comment: yeah its all closed and disposed @ZoharPeled

Comment: Not in the codw you've shared

Comment: @ZoharPeled its only part of code....full code is really lengthy...