# Parse series of strings into WHERE IN of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to build an Excel tool that allows users to input a series of article IDs and query our SQL server for said IDs. Problem is that all of these IDs are strings, so I have to input them as '123', '456', '789' - which is obviously not working if I were to execute the SP via

```
exec SP_test @articleID = '123', '456', '789'
```

The SP itself is pretty basic:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_test]
    @articleID as VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        ARTNR
        , ARTBEZ
    FROM table
    WHERE
        ARTNR IN 
            (@articleID)
END
GO
```

Like I said, this isn't working because it's not parsing '123' as '123' but rather 123.

I've then found a custom function to split strings in this thread: [How to pass string parameter with `IN` operator in stored procedure SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16872056/how-to-pass-string-parameter-with-in-operator-in-stored-procedure-sql-server-2)

If I then just execute the query itself (not as a SP), it's actually giving me the proper results:

```
SELECT
    ARTNR
    , ARTBEZ
FROM table
WHERE
    ARTNR IN 
        (select value from fn_split('123, 456, 789', ','))
```

But if I then try to turn that into my SP a la

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_test]
    @articleID as VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT
        ARTNR
        , ARTBEZ
    FROM table
    WHERE
        ARTNR IN 
            (select value from fn_split(@articleID, ','))
END
GO
```

it seems to again be parsing the articleIDs incorrectly.

Can anyone clue me in on how to get this to work properly? I've seen the string_split function being thrown around in this context, but m server's compatibility level isn't high enough for that.

Comment: Why not use a table type parameter?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)

Comment: *"it's not parsing '123' as '123' but rather 123."* It's not parsing it as `123` it's passing it as `'1'`. You can't fit more than one character in a `varchar(1)`.

Comment: Blimey, was kind of suspecting I was sleeping on something pretty simple - with varchar(MAX) it's actually working perfectly fine. Thank you, kind stranger.

Comment: If you are on SQL Server 2016+ you can use `STRING_SPLIT`

Comment: Not I **strongly** recommend the accepted answer in that link question, @PeterParker, it's a terrible solution.

Comment: Rather than that, honestly, use a set based inline table value function, , `STRING_SPLIT`, or switch to a table type parameter.